# TFS removing lock of other user

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, locking

I am hosting a project in `visualstudio.com` and what I have is only a VS studio 2012 installed. My friend has checked out and locked a file and then re-installed his windows, also creating a different name for his computer and thus he cannot check it in. Is it possible to **remove** that **lock** in any way? I am the one who created the project, so I should have all admin rights. It's just I do not know how to do it. I tried using

```
tf lock /lock:none /workspace:FRIEND-PC;friend@email.com filepath/filename.css /collection:https://***.visualstudio.com
```

however it seems to be searching in my computer which is not what I want at all. Nothing better I was able to find though :(

Comment: It is also possible to do this via the GUI, see [how-to-undo-another-users-checkout-in-tfs-via-the-gui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690351/how-to-undo-another-users-checkout-in-tfs-via-the-gui).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to undo another user’s checkout in TFS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690520/how-to-undo-another-user-s-checkout-in-tfs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to remove the lock this way:

```
C:\Users\****\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects>
tf undo /workspace:FRIEND-PC;friend@email.com    
/collection:https://xxxx.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection 
$/xxxx/ProjectFolder/ProjectName/filepath/filename.css
```

Answer (score 37):

I had this trouble too. I couldn't get the commands to work without errors. What did work for me was much simpler.

From within Visual Studio 2012(and 2013):

File -> Source Control -> Advanced -> Workspaces...

In the dialog that came up, I checked "Show remote workspaces" and the locked workspace came up in the window. I then selected it and clicked "Remove".

Comment: Worked for me! Had to close project and then reopen it

Comment: i had this problem because of my pc name is changed and i had to change my workspace and i tried so many things none of them worked but this is worked for me.

Comment: what locked workspace? the OP is talking about a locked file

Answer (score 14):

try

`tf workspace /delete FRIEND-PC;friend@email.com`

Deleteing the old workspace will remove any pending changes or locks.

Comment: I had to delete the workspace as well. doing the UNDO wasn't enough, since a file was locked pending an add in my remote workspace.

Comment: this command line will delete the pending locks and all history, be careful don't use it.

Comment: This worked for me, and 'TF undo' didn't, possibly because the locked file was deleted.

Comment: In powershell, you may need to use quotes: `tf workspace /delete "FRIEND-PC;Friend Name"`

Answer (score 6):

Here's what I did to remove the lock

```
tf undo /workspace:USER;Domain\User xyz.cs
```