# How to remove(?) pending edits for departed users?

Tags: version-control, tfs, azure-devops

My TFS terminology usage is probably all wrong because I'm new to it.

I have taken over a project. Two other users worked on it before me. Now they have left the company.

Lots of files in our TFS repositories say they are being edited by the departed users. I am assured by one of these users that this is wrong and I can safely make TFS not think the files are being edited.

However, I don't know how to do this. I am the only developer here and I want to make TFS think that no files are being edited at all.

There are thousands of files so I need a way to do this to all of them at once.

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690351/how-to-undo-another-users-checkout-in-tfs-via-the-gui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by following this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1690394/127434

I have to write more or else this answer will be converted to a comment and SO won't let me mark it as the answer.

I hope this is long enough now.